# How to make Windows Small Business Server 2011 bootable from an USB stick

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, windows-sbs

How would I go about make Windows Small Business Server 2011 install from an USB stick by making it bootable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's meant for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, but see if the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) will work.

Comment: I have used this to create a Jolicloud usb stick...and it worked for me...so I would assume if you had a valid ISO file of the win serv 11 disk it would work as well

Comment: @mjrider, interesting to know. I've tried non-windows disks and the utility has complained that it's not a valid disk image.

Comment: oh your right...it wasn't ms's tool but I think it was...the ubuntu version that I used...let me check what that is...

Comment: I think I used this http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer.exe

Comment: for other boot disks I use uNetBootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)