# what is the best way to install Small Business Server 2011?

Tags: installation, windows-sbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Windows Small Business Server 2011 bootable from an USB stick](https://superuser.com/questions/270784/how-to-make-windows-small-business-server-2011-bootable-from-an-usb-stick)

I have just downloaded Microsoft Small Business Server 2011 and it is 6.50 GB as this is too big to fit onto a CD what would you suggest is the best way for me to install this onto my server?

Comment: Honestly, [your last question](http://superuser.com/questions/270784/how-to-make-sbs-2011-bootable-from-a-usb-stick) is your best answer.  Flash it to a bootable USB drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn it to a DVD and use a DVD drive if you have one, if not they're like $25 these days; external USB ones can be had for under $100 in many places (around here).

Or

If it was downloaded as an ISO you should be able to use Microsoft's [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to install via a USB flash drive.

The link is a little hard to find on the page but it's there.  If you Google "Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool" there's a couple other download sources (like cnet.com).

Comment: can you get a DVD that will fit 6.5 GB on it though?

Comment: yes, Dual layer DVD's can do 8.5 gb....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR_DL